# Magento 2: What is loadPost?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, catalog-rules

Today, I have reviewed the the catalog-rule modules and found the a method named `loadPost` on controller during `save`. I don't know how it works but it saved  the rule data in serialized form in database. Before save, it converts the `actions` or `conditions` array data into serialized form.

Can anyone explain in brief that **What is use of this method and why does magento use this method** ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My answer was helpful for you? Do you have any other questions about the `loadPost`?

Comment: I'm glad to help you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method is used for one simple purpose: to convert a text-typed values ​​to the corresponding objects, if necessary. Typically, these objects are serialized data, such as conditions or actions or fields that store the date (as a string).

If you do not do this conversion, then in the model the date field will be represented exclusively in text form (as a string), and some methods will not be able to work with it correctly, because expect not the text but the date object.

If you have any data that can be submitted as text and sent through a form, you can also add their conversion in this method, and you can be sure that they will always be presented in the desired form (as an object).

#### Example:

1. Conditions as an array when form was submitted (in controller, before the `loadPost()`):

   [image: Conditions as an array when form was submitted]
2. `from_date` and `to_date` (in controller, before the `loadPost()`):

   [image: from and to date in controller]
3. Conditions after `_convertFlatToRecursive()` in the `loadPost()` method:

   [image: Conditions after _convertFlatToRecursive]

   as you can see **format is different**.
4. Conditions inside the object (rule) before they was set:

   [image: Conditions inside the rule model]
5. Conditions inside the object (rule) after they was set:

   [image: Conditions inside the rule model]

   as you can see, it's **completely working object** with own data and methods, **is not just array**.
6. Date field after the `loadPost()`, it is `DateTime` object:

   [image: Date field]

So, in case you want to work with a rule-model somewhere in the `afterSave` method or in observer you can use this objects and should **not worry about** *"How should I convert these values?"*.

Comment: Thanks.Got the point. It simply converts the data objects in to the string to save in database. Right ?

Comment: @zedBlackbeard No, it is converts a form-data to the objects to give you ability work with them and save them later in the database using own methods to convert an objects to database field values.

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau in my controller I save post data using the repository, in the repository there is no method like `loadpost` so how can I convert condition rule array in to serialize form and save to database. Thanks:)

Comment: @ChiragPatel You can use the `loadArray` method of the `Condition` object, like in the original `loadPost` method: `$this->getConditions()->setConditions([])->loadArray($arr['conditions'][1]);`

Comment: Thanks for the valuable time,  Actually I have an issue is  `loadPost` method is not providing a serialized value. can you please look into my questions https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/287102/magento-2-custom-catalog-condition-rule-not-saving-in-custom-module