# Magento 2 custom catalog condition rule not saving in custom module

Tags: magento2, database, adminhtml, uicomponent, catalog-rules

I have added custom catalog conditions to my custom module admin form. a condition drop-down is displayed fine and in post data, condition value is also getting. but I am unable to save condition value. below is my post condition array response.

```
[form_key] => dnqdkqI5vWvjfRnh
    [conditions] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [type] => Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Combine
                    [aggregator] => all
                    [value] => 1
                    [new_child] => 
                )

            [1--1] => Array
                (
                    [type] => Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product
                    [attribute] => sku
                    [operator] => ==
                    [value] => 24-WB06, 24-WB03
                )

        )
```

In admin side condition look like this.
[image]

Below is my code.

```
<fieldset name="storeproducts">
        <settings>
            <collapsible>true</collapsible>
            <label translate="true">Products Of The Store</label>
        </settings>
        <container name="conditions_apply_to" sortOrder="10">
            <htmlContent name="html_content">
                <block name="conditions_apply_to" class="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Test\Edit\Tab\Conditions" />
            </htmlContent>
        </container>
    </fieldset>
```

**Condition block file:**

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Test\Edit\Tab;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class Conditions extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic
{
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset
     */
    protected $_rendererFieldset;

    /**
     * @var \Magedelight\Productlabel\Block\Conditions
     */
    protected $_conditions;

    /**
     * @var \Namespace\Modulename\Model\TestFactory
     */
    private $TestFactory;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_nameInLayout = 'conditions_apply_to';

    /**
     * Conditions constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param \Magento\Rule\Block\Conditions $conditions
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset $rendererFieldset
     * @param \Namespace\Modulename\Model\TestFactory|null $TestFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Rule\Block\Conditions $conditions,
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset $rendererFieldset,
        \Namespace\Modulename\Model\TestFactory $TestFactory = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_conditions = $conditions;
        $this->_rendererFieldset = $rendererFieldset;
        $this->TestFactory = $TestFactory ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(\Magento\CatalogRule\Model\RuleFactory::class);
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function getTabClass()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getTabUrl()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function isAjaxLoaded()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('Conditions');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return __('Conditions');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare form before rendering HTML
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry(\Namespace\Modulename\Model\RegistryConstants::CURRENT_STORE_RULE);
        $form = $this->addTabToForm($model);
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

    /**
     * Handles addition of conditions tab to supplied form.
     *
     * @param \Magento\CatalogRule\Api\Data\RuleInterface $model
     * @param string $fieldsetId
     * @param string $formName
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Data\Form
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    protected function addTabToForm($model, $fieldsetId = 'conditions_fieldset', $formName = 'magedelight_Test_form')
    {
        if (!$model) {
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
            $model = $this->TestFactory->create();
            $model->load($id);
        }

        $conditionsFieldSetId = $model->getConditionsFieldSetId($formName);
        $newChildUrl = $this->getUrl(
            'catalog_rule/promo_catalog/newConditionHtml/form/' . $conditionsFieldSetId,
            ['form_namespace' => $formName]
        );

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('rule_');
        $renderer = $this->_rendererFieldset->setTemplate(
            'Magento_CatalogRule::promo/fieldset.phtml'
        )->setNewChildUrl(
            $newChildUrl
        )->setFieldSetId(
            $conditionsFieldSetId
        );

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            $fieldsetId,
            [
                'legend' => __(
                    'Apply the rule only if the following conditions are met (leave blank for all products).'
                )
            ]
        )->setRenderer(
            $renderer
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'conditions',
            'text',
            [
                'name'           => 'conditions',
                'label'          => __('Conditions'),
                'title'          => __('Conditions'),
                'required'       => true,
                'data-form-part' => $formName
            ]
        )->setRule(
            $model
        )->setRenderer(
            $this->_conditions
        );

        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $this->setConditionFormName($model->getConditions(), $formName, $conditionsFieldSetId);
        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * Handles addition of form name to condition and its conditions.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\AbstractCondition $conditions
     * @param string $formName
     * @param string $jsFormName
     * @return void
     */
    private function setConditionFormName(\Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\AbstractCondition $conditions, $formName, $jsFormName)
    {
        $conditions->setFormName($formName);
        $conditions->setJsFormObject($jsFormName);

        if ($conditions->getConditions() && is_array($conditions->getConditions())) {
            foreach ($conditions->getConditions() as $condition) {
                $this->setConditionFormName($condition, $formName, $jsFormName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Model File:**

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Model;

use Namespace\Modulename\Api\Data\TestInterfaceFactory;
use Namespace\Modulename\Api\Data\TestInterface;
//use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
use Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory;
use Magento\Rule\Model\AbstractModel;
use Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper;
use Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule\Action\CollectionFactory as RuleCollectionFactory;

class Test extends AbstractModel implements TestInterface
{

    /** @var \Namespace\Modulename\Model\Test\Condition\CombineFactory */
    protected $condCombineFactory;

    /** @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\CombineFactory */
    protected $condProdCombineF;

    /**
     * @var RuleCollectionFactory
     */
    private $actionCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * Prefix of model events names
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'productlabel_rules';

    /**
     * Parameter name in event
     *
     * In observe method you can use $observer->getEvent()->getRule() in this case
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_eventObject = 'rule';

    /**
     * Store already validated addresses and validation results
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $validatedAddresses = [];

    /**
     * Test constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate
     * @param Test\Condition\CombineFactory $condCombineFactory
     * @param RuleCollectionFactory $actionCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\CombineFactory $condProdCombineF
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource|null $resource
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb|null $resourceCollection
     * @param array $data
     * @param ExtensionAttributesFactory|null $extensionFactory
     * @param AttributeValueFactory|null $customAttributeFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json|null $serializer
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Namespace\Modulename\Model\Test\Condition\CombineFactory $condCombineFactory,
        RuleCollectionFactory $actionCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\CombineFactory $condProdCombineF,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = [],
        ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory = null,
        AttributeValueFactory $customAttributeFactory = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $serializer = null
    ) {
        $this->condCombineFactory = $condCombineFactory;
        $this->condProdCombineF = $condProdCombineF;
        $this->actionCollectionFactory = $actionCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $localeDate, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data, $extensionFactory, $customAttributeFactory, $serializer);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init(\Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Test::class);
        $this->setIdFieldName('Test_id');
    }

    /**
     * Get rule condition combine model instance
     *
     * @return \Namespace\Modulename\Model\Test\Condition\Combine
     */
    public function getConditionsInstance()
    {
        return $this->condCombineFactory->create();
    }

    /**
     * Get rule condition product combine model instance
     *
     * @return \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\Combine
     */
    public function getActionsInstance()
    {
        return $this->condProdCombineF->create();
    }

    /**
     * Check cached validation result for specific address
     *
     * @param Address $address
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasIsValidForAddress($address)
    {
        $addressId = $this->_getAddressId($address);
        return isset($this->validatedAddresses[$addressId]) ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Set validation result for specific address to results cache
     *
     * @param Address $address
     * @param bool $validationResult
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setIsValidForAddress($address, $validationResult)
    {
        $addressId = $this->_getAddressId($address);
        $this->validatedAddresses[$addressId] = $validationResult;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get cached validation result for specific address
     *
     * @param Address $address
     * @return bool
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.BooleanGetMethodName)
     */
    public function getIsValidForAddress($address)
    {
        $addressId = $this->_getAddressId($address);
        return isset($this->validatedAddresses[$addressId]) ? $this->validatedAddresses[$addressId] : false;
    }

    /**
     * Return id for address
     *
     * @param Address $address
     * @return string
     */
    private function _getAddressId($address)
    {
        if ($address instanceof Address) {
            return $address->getId();
        }
        return $address;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $formName
     * @return string
     */
    public function getConditionsFieldSetId($formName = '')
    {
        return $formName . 'rule_conditions_fieldset_' . $this->getId();
    }
}
```

What is the process to save condition value to the database?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Right now, which type of output saved in DB and what's type of DB column field?

Comment: Right now no value save in column, and DB column field name is `conditions_serialized` and type is text. and value will be saved as serializing form.

Comment: I am following this tutorial https://www.mageworx.com/blog/2016/09/magento-2-module-with-conditions-model-fieldset/

Answer (score -1):

I'm a little late to answer :D, but it might be helpfull for others.
In the controller, you have to serialize this array.

app/code/Vendor/Rules/Controller/Adminhtml/Example/Rule/Save.php

```
protected function prepareData($data)
{

    if (isset($data['rule']['conditions'])) {
        $data['conditions'] = $this->_json->serialize($data['rule']['conditions']);
    }

    unset($data['rule']);

    return $data;
}
```

Using this : \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json

Answer (score -1):

> Follow the Below link is a full Example.

[**Click Here For Part 1**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344611/82670)

[**Click Here For Part 2**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344612/82670)

[**Click Here For Part 3**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344613/82670)

**[Check condition with products in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344617/82670)**

***I Hope This Helps You.***